# XYPlot change default background color to white

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I tried to implement an XYPlot in a Fragment of my Android App. However the app's design is white while the default background color of the graph is black.

I've tried to change the color to White in the XML file as well as from code but the graph remains black.[it always looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1lQ1.jpg)

This is my XML-file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".OverviewFragment">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/plt_graph"
        style="@style/APDefacto.Dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundColor="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is what I've tried to change it from code. Note, that I am in a Fragment and not in an Activity.

```
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) view.findViewById(R.id.plt_graph);
        Button btShowHealthGraph = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btHealthIndex);
        Paint color = new Paint();
        color.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        plot.getGraph().setBackgroundPaint(color);
        plot.getGraph().setGridBackgroundPaint(color);
```